# Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:8888

Tags: c#, сервер, веб-сервер

Вот код, на другой машине все работало, сервер давал ответ, сейчас пишет

> Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на
>   подключение 127.0.0.1:8888

Брандмауэр выключен

```
static void Main()
    {
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
        string mySrc = HttpMethods.Get("https://example.com", "https://example.com", cc);
        Console.WriteLine(mySrc);

    }
public static string Get(string url, string referer, CookieContainer cc)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        req.Method = "GET";
        req.CookieContainer = cc;
        req.UserAgent = "";
        req.Referer = referer;

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        cc.Add(resp.Cookies);

        string pageSrc;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSrc = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return pageSrc;
    }
```

Comment: У вас локальный прокси 127.0.0.1:8888? или что то редиректит туда? или троян? или шпион? :)

Comment: Очевидно, на другой машине какая-то программа слушала порт 8888, а на этой - нет.

Comment: Какие танцы с бубном нужно проделать теперь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте настройки прокси-сервера. Они могут быть указаны в двух местах:

1. Системные настройки. "Свойства браузера" (можно найти через поиск в меню "Пуск", можно найти через настройки IE или Chrome) - вкладка "Подключения" - кнопка "Настройка сети" - и там уже будут видны настройки прокси-сервера.
2. Конфигурационный файл вашей же программы (в проекте это app.config или web.config, но после сборки первый становится файлом ИмяПрограммы.exe.config) - там прокси-сервер задаётся по пути `system.net/defaultProxy`

Если оба места пусты - значит, адрес 127.0.0.1:8888 - это и есть адрес сервера, к которому вы почему-то подключаетесь. Вам нужно указать правильный адрес для подключения.

Comment: неужели по умолчанию в конфиг добавляется system.net/defaultProxy ? мне кажется это специально надо туда прописать руками.

Comment: @NewView да, надо. Но если проект достался от коллеги - там это могло быть прописано. Например, для отладки в связке с Fiddler.

Comment: да, верно, по наследству может быть что угодно..